How to I unblock Iframed cookies?
Before you respond. Yes I'm aware it's 2024 and iframes are terrible. I'm forced to use this solution. It's a speed to market question. Yes, I also agree with you iframes cause more issues than they are worth and ultimately reduce speed to market. If you want Ill connect you to my management and you can also try explaining to them. Otherwise, let us move on and try to solve the problem.
We are trying to embed a website A.com into a partner website B.com via an iframe. One issue I found is A.com cookies are blocked unless we add SameSite=None to all the cookies. However, A.com also includes static content from other domains where we cannot modify cookies to add the SameSite attribute. Is there some way to make the iframe cookies work without modifying them? Technically speaking, I do not understand why they are considered "3rd party" cookies by the browser. Yes it is a cross domain iframe, but A.com only sets cookies for A.com. It is not as if we are trying to set cookies for B.com. If we cannot set cookies in the iframe without them being considered 3rd party then just remove iframes from the html spec already since most modern websites are complex and will have this issue.
